# Passing List parameter from Controller to JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model

I want to pass List value from Spring MVC Controller to JSP page.When I do this I am getting this result like above.

```
${ad}

${ad} 
${list.ad} 
${list.soyad} 
${list.yas}
```

But my list is filling from my dao.I have tested it.Here is my codes.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"liste","kayitlar"})
public class ListeController {

 @Autowired
IKayitListe service;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String liste(ModelMap model){
    List<Kayit> list = service.getKayitlar();
    model.addAttribute("list", list);
    model.addAttribute("ad", "Mesut Emre");
    return "liste";
 }
}


 <c:out value="${ad}"/>        
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="{list}">            
           <c:out value="${list.ad}" />             
           <c:out value="${list.soyad}" />              
           <c:out value="${list.yas}" />        
        </c:forEach>
```

Why can't I get the list value and other value that I passed?What is going wrong in these codes?

Comment: try changing    
    
      <c:forEach items="${list}" var="{list}">

to

       <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listVar">

Comment: Bu why can't I get passed "ad" value in Model?

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about SPRING mvc, But should'nt the return type be the list name without the double quotes? It's populating it as far as this you were saying.